# Date format is differing between Microsoft Active Directory, OpenLDAP and Apache DS

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap, apacheds

We are in the process of implementing common client application for Microsoft Active Directory, LDAP and Apache DS. As part of our analysis below is the sample date formats from each LDAP server.

Microsoft Active Directory:
Create Timestamp: 20200309090040.0Z

OpenLDAP:
Create Timestamp: 20200303122535Z

ApacheDS:
Create Timestamp: 20200224053308.405Z

We can see data formats changing between the LDAP servers. Could anyone help which format each server is following with appropriate pointer if any to handle all there servers in same code or same client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They all look like the same format, except AD and Apache have decimal places indicating fractions of a second.

The format is this:

```
YYYY MM DD HH mm ss.sss Z
2020 03 09 09 00 40.0   Z
2020 03 03 12 25 35     Z
2020 02 24 05 33 08.405 Z
```

The `Z` means "Zulu time", otherwise known as GMT or UTC.